# Does QED provide a closed form for Coulomb logarithms?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, electrons, scattering, coulombs-law, diffusion

The classical models for the integrand as well as the cut-offs in computing the [Coulomb logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_logarithm) are pretty rough.

> Does quantum electrodynamics have definite expressions for the quantity $\mathrm{ln}(\Lambda)$?

Specifically, I'm motivated by the applications for electron diffusion coefficients.

And I could imagine the answer also answers this: Is the kind of Colombo logarithm for other charges (color charges, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

The Coulomb logarithm is a heuristic cutoff. For length scales beyond the Debye radius, electrons in a plasma see a smoothed electric field, not the $1/r$ potential of the neighboring electrons. Hence, when computing two-body scattering, for electrons with an impact parameter too far out, that particular charge will be screened and cut off.

Thus, in any many-body context where you have charge screening and something along the lines of a Debye radius, you will have something equivalent. The logarithm is the statement that if you get too far away from a scattering center, the relevant charges are screened by the intervening charges, and don't see each other in a binary way.

So, in answer to your question: the active vacuum (a many-body system) does screen the $1/r$ potential, so in some sense that happens. But the Coulomb log is a much more plasma physics concept than a QED one.